# Emergency room R simulation program problem

Tags: r, simulation

The problem statement is the following:

> In an emergency room two nurses are doing their shifts, if there are
>   no patients waiting, the incoming patient will be tended by the two
>   nurses, if there are two patients incoming, each take one to tend and
>   if the nurses are tending to a patient and then another one comes in,
>   the nurse should go to tend the patient that just came in and the time
>   that's left for the patient 1 is reduced by ten minutes.

Now, this is what I've got so far in my program:
[In reply to Jorge Rodríguez]

```
#Prueba funcion post.seize()
library(simmer)
library(dplyr)


set.seed(1234)

emergency <- simmer()

pacient <- 
  trajectory("pacient trajectory")%>%
  log_("Here I am")%>%
  set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(emerency)})%>%
  seize("nurse")%>%
  log_(function() {paste("Waited: ", now(emergency) - get_attribute(emergency, "start_time"))})%>%
  timeout(function() {runif(1, 0.2, 1)})%>%
  release("nurse")%>%
  log_(function() {paste("Finished: ", now(emergency))})  



emergency <- 
  simmer("emergency")%>%
  add_resource("nurse", 2)%>%
  add_generator("pacient", pacient, function() {c(rexp(1, 0.2)), -1)})%>%



emergency %>% run(until=400)

emergency %>%
  get_mon_arrivals %>%
  dplyr::mutate(waiting_time = end_time - start_time - activity_time)

arrivals<- emergency %>% get_mon_arrivals(per_resource=T)
waiting <- arrivals$end_time - arrivals$start_time - arrivals$activity_time
waiting
mean(waiting)
```

I think I've got much of the login working in the code but what it's really hard for me to see is the part:

> if the nurses are tending to a patient and then another one comes in,
>   the nurse should go to tend the patient that just came in and the time
>   that's left for the patient 1 is reduced by ten minutes.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to answer?

Comment: I want to know how can I tell if the two nurses are tending the same patient so that I can tell one to go to another patient if one comes to the emergency room while they're both busy in the same one.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to answer, because your snippet implements a classic M/G/2 with a uniform service time. Your problem statement defines state-dependent features, but none of them are captured here. This topic has been already discussed in the simmer mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/simmer-devel/QpEwREov-yE/IpZTZgvICwAJ